# The use of an accept() in the Visitor pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am looking into using the Visitor pattern. Some of the examples I see suggest using an accept(Visitor) function in every Element subclass. Is the idea of that function just so that a visitor can visit a collection that contains polymorphic types? In this code, I use a visitor to do two types of accumulation, and it doesn't require accept().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IntItem
{
public:
  IntItem(const int a) : IntData(a){}

  int IntData;
};

class DoubleItem
{
public:
  DoubleItem(const double a) : DoubleData(a){}

  double DoubleData;
};

class Visitor
{
public:
  virtual void Visit(IntItem &item) = 0;
  virtual void Visit(DoubleItem &item) = 0;
};


class SumAccumulator : public Visitor
{
public:

  SumAccumulator() : Sum(0) {}
  void Visit(IntItem &item)
  {
    Sum += item.IntData;
  }

  void Visit(DoubleItem &item)
  {
    Sum += item.DoubleData;
  }

  double Sum;
};

class AverageAccumulator : public Visitor
{
public:

  AverageAccumulator() : Average(0), Counter(0) {}
  void Visit(IntItem &item)
  {
    Counter++;
    Average = (Counter - 1) * Average + item.IntData;
    Average /= Counter;
  }

  void Visit(DoubleItem &item)
  {
    Counter++;
    Average = (Counter - 1) * Average + item.DoubleData;
    Average /= Counter;
  }

  int Counter;
  double Average;
};

class IntCollection
{
public:
  void Visit(Visitor &visitor)
  {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < IntItems.size(); ++i)
      {
      visitor.Visit(IntItems[i]);
      }
  }

  void AddIntItem(const IntItem& item)
  {
    IntItems.push_back(item);
  }

private:
  std::vector<IntItem> IntItems;

};

class DoubleCollection
{
public:
  void Visit(Visitor &visitor)
  {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < DoubleItems.size(); ++i)
      {
      visitor.Visit(DoubleItems[i]);
      }
  }

  void AddDoubleItem(const DoubleItem& item)
  {
    DoubleItems.push_back(item);
  }

private:
  std::vector<DoubleItem> DoubleItems;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /////// Ints ////////
  IntCollection intCollection;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
    intCollection.AddIntItem(IntItem(i));
    }

  SumAccumulator intSumAccumulator;
  intCollection.Visit(intSumAccumulator);
  std::cout << "int sum: " << intSumAccumulator.Sum << std::endl;

  AverageAccumulator intAverageAccumulator;
  intCollection.Visit(intAverageAccumulator);
  std::cout << "int average: " << intAverageAccumulator.Average << std::endl;

  /////// Doubles ////////
  DoubleCollection doubleCollection;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
    doubleCollection.AddDoubleItem(DoubleItem(static_cast<double>(i) + .1));
    }
  SumAccumulator doubleSumAccumulator;
  doubleCollection.Visit(doubleSumAccumulator);
  std::cout << "double sum: " << doubleSumAccumulator.Sum << std::endl;

  AverageAccumulator doubleAverageAccumulator;
  doubleCollection.Visit(doubleAverageAccumulator);
  std::cout << "double average: " << doubleAverageAccumulator.Average << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In this code, I do use accept(), and the only difference is that the container can contain objects of varying types in the same container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class IntElement;
class DoubleElement;

class Visitor
{
public:
  virtual void visit(IntElement *e) = 0;
  virtual void visit(DoubleElement *e) = 0;
};

class Element
{
public:
  virtual void accept(class Visitor &v) = 0;
};

class IntElement: public Element
{
public:
  IntElement(int i) : IntData(i){}
  /*virtual*/void accept(Visitor &v)
  {
    v.visit(this);
  }

  int IntData;
};

class DoubleElement: public Element
{
public:
  DoubleElement(double d) : DoubleData(d){}
  /*virtual*/void accept(Visitor &v)
  {
    v.visit(this);
  }

  double DoubleData;
};

class SumVisitor: public Visitor
{
public:
  SumVisitor() : Sum(0){}
  /*virtual*/void visit(IntElement *e)
  {
    Sum += e->IntData;
  }
  /*virtual*/void visit(DoubleElement *e)
  {
    Sum += e->DoubleData;
  }

  double Sum;
};

class AverageVisitor: public Visitor
{
public:
  AverageVisitor() : Counter(0) , Average(0){}
  /*virtual*/void visit(IntElement *e)
  {
    Counter++;
    Average = (Counter - 1) * Average + e->IntData;
    Average /= Counter;
  }
  /*virtual*/void visit(DoubleElement *e)
  {
    Counter++;
    Average = (Counter - 1) * Average + e->DoubleData;
    Average /= Counter;
  }
  double Average;
  int Counter;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Element*> elements;
  elements.push_back(new IntElement(0));
  elements.push_back(new IntElement(1));
  elements.push_back(new DoubleElement(2));
  elements.push_back(new DoubleElement(3));

  SumVisitor sumVisitor;
  AverageVisitor averageVisitor;
  for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++)
    {
    elements[i]->accept(sumVisitor);
    elements[i]->accept(averageVisitor);
    }
  std::cout << "sum: " << sumVisitor.Sum << std::endl;
  std::cout << "average: " << averageVisitor.Average << std::endl;
}
```

Is this distinction correct? That is, if I only plan on having homogeneous containers I do not need to implement accept functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this distinction correct? That is, if I only plan on having
>   homogeneous containers I do not need to implement accept functions?

Yes, that's the essence of the pattern.

Basically, if you have a relatively stable `Element` hierarchy, it allows you to add new `Visitor` derivatives as necessary.  The visitors can then be invoked without the invoker knowing the concrete type of the element being operated on.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Also, in all of the examples I've seen they have Visit() functions for multiple overloaded types inside the same Visitor class. The logic seems to need to be duplicated anyway, so why not make a separate visitor with a single visit() function?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your question but the reason each visitor has a `visit` overload for each element type is so that the visitor can discover the concrete type of the element being operated on by having the element call `visitor->visit( this )`.  This is a roundabout way of accomplishing double dispatch in a language without built-in support for it.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm saying is instead of:

```
class SumVisitor: public Visitor
{
public:
  SumVisitor() : Sum(0){}
  /*virtual*/void visit(IntElement *e)
  {
    Sum += e->IntData;
  }
  /*virtual*/void visit(DoubleElement *e)
  {
    Sum += e->DoubleData;
  }

  double Sum;
};
```

Why not have:

```
class IntSumVisitor: public Visitor
{
public:
  SumVisitor() : Sum(0){}
  /*virtual*/void visit(IntElement *e)
  {
    Sum += e->IntData;
  }

  double Sum;
};

class DoubleSumVisitor: public Visitor
{
public:
  DoubleSumVisitor() : Sum(0){}
  /*virtual*/void visit(IntElement *e)
  {
    Sum += e->IntData;
  }

  int Sum;
};
```

? Does it help anything to have multiple overloads in a single visitor class? Or does it just introduce unnecessary dependencies?